# XAMARIN - App crash when repeating an action many times (~50 times)

Tags: android, xamarin, crash

I have an android application which be developed by XAMARIN.

The app has a left menu (contains categories) and after select an item on the menu it will load detail information to the right panel.

But when I repeat selecting between items about 50 times (to stress app), the app is crashed with below output information in logcat.

Anyone can suggestion me about what's the reason and how to fix?
Many thanks.

```
06-08 13:35:08.734 D/Mono    ( 5943): GC_BRIDGE waiting for bridge processing to finish
06-08 13:35:08.742 D/Mono    ( 5943): GC_BRIDGE waiting for bridge processing to finish
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128] JNI ERROR (app bug): weak global reference table overflow (max=51200)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128] weak global reference table dump:
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]   Last 10 entries (of 51200):
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]     51199: 0x13036800 android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]     51198: 0x13036400 android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]     51197: 0x16657c00 android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]     51196: 0x145ff000 android.widget.LinearLayout
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]     51195: 0x12cfd5b0 md53d7173397eb52e2423f57ce834c3c69a.LearningRecordViewHolder
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]     51194: 0x12e5fc00 android.widget.LinearLayout
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]     51193: 0x12e7a400 android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]     51192: 0x12e8f000 android.widget.LinearLayout
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]     51191: 0x12e8ec00 android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]     51190: 0x12e8e400 android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]   Summary:
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]      1329 of android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView (1329 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]       150 of android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout (150 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of md523f7f384e2d46b96ecbe34fad34e2210.RegisterActivity
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]       299 of com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions (299 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]      5075 of android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (5075 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]       200 of android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView (200 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        50 of md5a37ff8ffd51c72323bae06715b700c41.LearningHistoryFragment (50 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        50 of md5a37ff8ffd51c72323bae06715b700c41.NoticesFragment (50 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        55 of md53d7173397eb52e2423f57ce834c3c69a.LearningRecordViewHolder (55 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText (3 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]       183 of android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager (183 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         2 of android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton (2 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]       200 of android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton (200 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]       993 of mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor (993 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        30 of android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl (30 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        43 of md5a37ff8ffd51c72323bae06715b700c41.PerformanceInfoFragment (43 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        50 of md53d7173397eb52e2423f57ce834c3c69a.NoticeAdapter (50 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        47 of md59db4fab6d8023623ced3d0ce5771bf1e.ViewPagerPerformance (47 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        50 of md53d7173397eb52e2423f57ce834c3c69a.PerformancePagerAdapter (50 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        50 of md53d7173397eb52e2423f57ce834c3c69a.CalendarAdapter (50 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        49 of md53d7173397eb52e2423f57ce834c3c69a.HomeAdapter (49 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        50 of md5a37ff8ffd51c72323bae06715b700c41.ComprehensionFragment (50 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        48 of md5a37ff8ffd51c72323bae06715b700c41.SchoolPerformanceFragment (48 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        50 of md5a37ff8ffd51c72323bae06715b700c41.CalendarFragment (50 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        51 of md53c05f8cc7dd658454811c4e83aaed3e0.RadarChart (51 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        40 of mono.android.view.ViewTreeObserver_OnGlobalLayoutListenerImplementor (40 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        50 of md59db4fab6d8023623ced3d0ce5771bf1e.CalendarView (50 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        50 of android.widget.GridView (50 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        29 of md53d7173397eb52e2423f57ce834c3c69a.CalendarViewHolder (29 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        56 of md53d7173397eb52e2423f57ce834c3c69a.BlankViewHolder (56 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]       185 of md53d7173397eb52e2423f57ce834c3c69a.SelfStudyViewHolder (185 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        44 of md53d7173397eb52e2423f57ce834c3c69a.SchoolPerformanceAdapter (44 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]       234 of md53d7173397eb52e2423f57ce834c3c69a.SchoolPerformanceAdapter_ViewHolder (234 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]       101 of md59db4fab6d8023623ced3d0ce5771bf1e.CustomImageView (101 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.881 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         6 of android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar (6 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        85 of mono.android.view.View_OnTouchListenerImplementor (85 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        42 of mono.android.widget.AdapterView_OnItemClickListenerImplementor (42 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        50 of md52bc3124d6d8460b4884ad0126527d870.ImageLoadingListener (50 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]       118 of md5bf4be4f7ef068fce466e16e1a6af57e5.EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener (118 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        50 of md53d7173397eb52e2423f57ce834c3c69a.LearningHistoryAdapter (50 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        19 of md53d7173397eb52e2423f57ce834c3c69a.MenuAdapter (19 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        45 of md5a37ff8ffd51c72323bae06715b700c41.TopFragment (45 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        49 of android.support.v4.view.ViewPager (49 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        49 of android.support.design.widget.TabLayout (49 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        34 of mono.android.support.v4.view.ViewPager_OnPageChangeListenerImplementor (34 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        49 of md53d7173397eb52e2423f57ce834c3c69a.CustomPagerAdapter (49 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]       151 of android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab (151 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        49 of md5a37ff8ffd51c72323bae06715b700c41.HomeFragment (49 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        34 of mono.android.support.design.widget.TabLayout_OnTabSelectedListenerImplementor (34 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        57 of md53d7173397eb52e2423f57ce834c3c69a.ImportantNoticeViewHolder (57 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        56 of md53d7173397eb52e2423f57ce834c3c69a.NoticeViewHolder (56 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]      1166 of mono.android.runtime.JavaObject (1166 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        50 of md59db4fab6d8023623ced3d0ce5771bf1e.CalendarView_CustomCalendarAdapter (50 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        34 of md53d7173397eb52e2423f57ce834c3c69a.SummaryInformationViewHolder (34 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        50 of java.util.GregorianCalendar (50 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         4 of java.lang.Class (4 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]       147 of java.lang.String (147 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of byte[] (2496 elements) (3 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (4096 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (6912 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         4 of byte[] (7488 elements) (4 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of byte[] (8976 elements) (3 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         2 of byte[] (10816 elements) (2 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (12288 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         2 of byte[] (12544 elements) (2 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (15360 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         5 of byte[] (16384 elements) (5 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         4 of byte[] (17920 elements) (4 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (18496 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of byte[] (20736 elements) (3 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (21760 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (26240 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (27968 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (30720 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (30976 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (32384 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (36608 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        21 of byte[] (36864 elements) (21 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         2 of byte[] (38272 elements) (2 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (43264 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        27 of byte[] (46656 elements) (27 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (54144 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (57344 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (57408 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         6 of byte[] (57600 elements) (6 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         2 of byte[] (61952 elements) (2 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         2 of byte[] (62500 elements) (2 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        17 of byte[] (65536 elements) (17 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of byte[] (82944 elements) (3 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         2 of byte[] (84480 elements) (2 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (102400 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of byte[] (129600 elements) (3 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of byte[] (141312 elements) (3 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (146432 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of byte[] (147456 elements) (3 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         4 of byte[] (195536 elements) (4 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        12 of byte[] (215040 elements) (12 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (230400 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (423168 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         5 of byte[] (478864 elements) (5 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (589824 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (652800 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (659854 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        54 of byte[] (720000 elements) (54 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (815490 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        23 of byte[] (1104000 elements) (23 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (1774080 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        11 of byte[] (2208000 elements) (11 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (2479200 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (2688000 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of byte[] (16008000 elements)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        51 of java.util.HashMap (51 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        63 of java.lang.Integer (63 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        31 of java.lang.DexCache (31 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         3 of dalvik.system.PathClassLoader (1 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         2 of com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater (2 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of android.widget.FrameLayout
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]      1932 of android.widget.TextView (1932 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        50 of android.widget.ListView (50 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]      5782 of android.widget.LinearLayout (5782 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         2 of com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow (2 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]       392 of android.widget.RelativeLayout (392 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of android.graphics.Typeface
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         2 of android.content.res.Resources (2 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of android.util.DisplayMetrics
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of android.view.MotionEvent
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of android.os.Looper
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        63 of android.graphics.Bitmap (63 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of android.net.ConnectivityManager
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of android.app.ContextImpl
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        47 of android.view.ViewTreeObserver (47 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        21 of android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams (21 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        77 of android.graphics.Path (77 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        29 of android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable (29 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of android.graphics.Path$Direction
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]     29949 of android.view.RenderNode (29949 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         6 of android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable (6 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]       110 of android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser (110 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]         1 of android.os.PowerManager
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128]        30 of android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams (30 unique instances)
06-08 13:35:08.882 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:128] 
06-08 13:35:08.971 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/runtime.cc:404] Runtime aborting...
06-08 13:35:08.971 F/art     ( 5943): art/runtime/runtime.cc:404] Aborting thread:
```

Comment: It seems that this is memory link, can you show the code about what you did when you select an item on the menu?

Comment: because of security problem so I can't post the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the application creates so much global reference.
But I don't know how to detect which line code creates global reference without destroying.
So I close this question to ask another.